# Unable to get Memory Leak Reports for a process that runs through watchdog and uses shared objects

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, memcheck

I am running a process using valgrind that uses multiple shared objects.
The valgrind command is:

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --log-file=/tmp/PROGNAME.out -v PROGNAME ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ARG4 ARG5 ARG6 ARG7
```

My **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is pointing to the correct library path as well.

But my `valgrind` report generated doesn't show the section of `LEAK SUMMARY` or `HEAP SUMMARY`.

Any suggestions as to what's being done incorrectly here would be of great help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621418/valgrind-find-memory-leak-in-a-shared-library This may help.

Comment: you need to be more specific about the watchdog.  How do you *run the program through it?*

Comment: Your program does terminate? Valgrind by default doesn't report leaks until the app under test ends.

Comment: Can you post more output from Valgrind?